# Dissassembling a zip file

Tags: disassembly

> Perhaps similar to [Reverse engineering zip file](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4251/reverse-engineering-zip-file), but my problem is clearly different

---

Do zip files contain some specific sort of uniform code? What I mean by this is: Is it possible to analyze some properties of the zip file? Editing a zip with a hex editor is not helpful at all, as it is unintelligible to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the ZIP file format is thoroughly documented here: https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT

You can use [010 Editor](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/)'s [ZIP template](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/templates/files/ZIPTemplate.bt) for analyzing ZIP files:

[image: ZIP]